# t-sql function that returns table. How to make a view that returns multiple tables (union -ed)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a function that returns a table. (t-sql microsoft sql server 2008)

I call the function like:

```
Select * from calcSomething( 21 );
```

How would I call a function with multiple ID's. And all UNIONed in one table.

Something like:

```
select * from USERS, CalcSomething( USERS.id )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  cs.*
FROM    users u
CROSS APPLY
        calcSomething(u.id) cs
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using a [CROSS APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT u.*, c.*
FROM Users u
CROSS APPLY calcSomething(u.id) as c
```

Comment: Thanx For the answer!

But it doesn't work. I get an error

**Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '.'.**

Comment: what is the code you are running?  I edited my answer to add the aliases to the *

Comment: here's exact code I run
`  select o.*, c.*
  from  oseba o
  cross apply  GRID_st_man_izp_za_dm ( o.ose_id  ) as  c 
`

Comment: @DtestDdemo seems like something is missing because the code should be working.  Can you edit your question and post both the error, code you are running and the function code?

Comment: I solved it!! 
The problem was that I had database compatibility level let to "SQL server 2000 (80)" 
When I changed it to Sql server 2008 (100) it solved everything

Comment: @DtestDdemo if one of the answers helped you with your issue, you should consider accepting it via the checkmark on the left of an answer.